# Laravel controller getting ids from array at the returned collection

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have php laravel framework project (laravel-8) and at DB , I have column which has array of objects like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "G0",
    "name": "Social-Emotional Understanding",
    "questions": [
        {
            "gId": "G0",
            "id": 1,
            "question_id": 34,
            "question_title": "Age - appropriate social- emotional understanding. Clearly understands facial expressions, gestures, tone of voice, and body language of\r\nothers. Able to under - stand that others may have a different perspective and what that perspective may be.",
            "question_note": null,
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer_index": "1",
                    "answer_text": "yes",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G1",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "1"
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "2",
                    "answer_text": "No",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "noGroup",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "3",
                    "answer_text": "N/A",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "noGroup",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "gId": "G0",
            "id": 2,
            "question_id": 35,
            "question_title": "Mildly impaired social-emotional understanding. Responsive to most facial expressions and expressions of emotion in others’ gestures and\r\nbody language, but these cues may need to be slightly exaggerated. Subtler expressions such as mild sarcasm, doubt, or ambiguity are\r\nsometimes not understood. The ability to take another’s perspective is inconsistent.",
            "question_note": null,
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer_index": "1",
                    "answer_text": "yes",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G1",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "2"
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "2",
                    "answer_text": "No",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "noGroup",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "3",
                    "answer_text": "N/A",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G1",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "1.5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "gId": "G0",
            "id": 3,
            "question_id": 36,
            "question_title": "Moderately impaired social - emotional understanding. Shows an under - standing of facial expressions, tone of voice, and body language\r\nonly when these cues are exaggerated. Is likely to ignore or misunderstand or perspective of others.",
            "question_note": null,
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer_index": "1",
                    "answer_text": "yes",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G1",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "3"
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "2",
                    "answer_text": "No",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "noGroup",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "3",
                    "answer_text": "N/A",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G1",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "2.5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "G1",
    "name": "Emotional expression and regulation of emotions",
    "questions": [
        {
            "gId": "G1",
            "id": 3,
            "question_id": 104,
            "question_title": "Moderately abnormal emotional response. Expression of emotions is flat, excessive, or frequently inconsistent with situation or content\r\nof verbalized topic. May display greater emotion than expected about special interest or idiocy necrotic concerns. Ability to describe or\r\nunderstand emotional states in self is limited. Serious problems with emotional regulation that occur frequently in at least one setting.",
            "question_note": null,
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer_index": "1",
                    "answer_text": "Yes",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G2",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "3"
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "2",
                    "answer_text": "No",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "noGroup",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "3",
                    "answer_text": "N/A",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G2",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "2.5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "gId": "G1",
            "id": 2,
            "question_id": 103,
            "question_title": "Mildly abnormal emotional response. Emotional expressions are relatively flat, distorted, or slightly exaggerated. Nonverbal expression of\r\nemotions does not always match verbal content. Able to describe several emotions in self but limited compared to developmental level.\r\nMay have intermittent emotional regulation problems.",
            "question_note": null,
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer_index": "1",
                    "answer_text": "Yes",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G2",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "2"
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "2",
                    "answer_text": "No",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "noGroup",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer_index": "3",
                    "answer_text": "N/A",
                    "answer_image": null,
                    "answers_redirection_group_index": "G2",
                    "answers_redirection_group_question": "noQuestion",
                    "degree": "1.5"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

How can I create array from all "question_id" ? so I can return this questions from question table by using " whereIn('id', $ids)->get(); "

so the neede array must be like $ids = [34,35,36,104,103] so I will use this array to get this questions from question table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.